# Pandas/Numpy Changed File Type Read in Now Get Calculation Error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, complex-numbers

I was reading in an Excel file with Pandas, extracting a Numpy array from 2 sets of 9 columns, and creating a complex number array for doing complex number matrix multiplication.  The original data is just decimal values, but depending on the column the values come from decides whether they are real or imaginary.  I originally wrote the code reading from and Excel file as an xlsx.  Then I changed it to a csv file source, I get the same individual 3X3 matrix in both cases which I am combining into a complex matrix.  When I run the code, I get the following error.

```
        TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-e87255037c7f> in <module>()
     11     while counter < count_net_r:
     12         n = counter # int
---> 13         net = (net_r[n] + 1.0j * net_x[n])
     14         counter = counter + 1
     15         net_seq.append(net)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex'
```

My code for readin in the file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Report.csv')

# uses Pandas .loc to extract and create the network equivalent R per phase components into an array
# for multiplication to calculate the sequence matrix - REAL Part
r = df.loc[df['Code\n'] == 'Network Equivalent', 'NetEq Z R AA':'NetEq Z R CC']
rr = r.shape[0]
net_r = r.values.reshape(rr,3,3)

# uses Pandas .loc to extract and create the network equivalent X per phase components into an array
# for multiplication to calculate the sequence matrix - COMPLEX Part
x = df.loc[df['Code\n'] == 'Network Equivalent', 'NetEq Z X AA':'NetEq Z X CC']
xx = x.shape[0]
net_x = x.values.reshape(xx,3,3)

# loop to concatenate the R & X into one array of complex numbers
# if the R and X matrices are of unequal lengths then prints unequal length so it can be solved and attempted again
count_net_r = len(net_r) # int
count_net_x = len(net_x) # int
net = [] # list
net_seq = [] # list
counter = 0
if count_net_r != count_net_x:
    print('Network Equivalent matrices are not equivalent')
else:
    while counter < count_net_r:
        n = counter # int
        net = (net_r[n] + 1.0j * net_x[n])
        counter = counter + 1
        net_seq.append(net)
net_seq = np.array(net_seq)
```

All I changed is how the file is read in.  So what do I need to change to get this code to work?  Or, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

So I have no clue why, but all I did was change the type on creation of the two arrays.

```
# uses Pandas .loc to extract and create the network equivalent R per phase components into an array
# for multiplication to calculate the sequence matrix - REAL Part
r = df.loc[df['Code\n'] == 'Network Equivalent', 'NetEq Z R AA':'NetEq Z R CC'].astype('float')
rr = r.shape[0]
net_r = r.values.reshape(rr,3,3)

# uses Pandas .loc to extract and create the network equivalent X per phase components into an array
# for multiplication to calculate the sequence matrix - COMPLEX Part
x = df.loc[df['Code\n'] == 'Network Equivalent', 'NetEq Z X AA':'NetEq Z X CC'].astype('float')
xx = x.shape[0]
net_x = x.values.reshape(xx,3,3)
```

I thought even in a csv file type a number is a number.  Guess I was wrong.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)